How can i send float value to holding register using QModbusDataUnit::HoldingRegisters? (QT modbus RTU)
Just got an 485 device, need to send data to run some function.
The device's manual says its starting address is 16/17, and the data type is float type.
I've tried to read the registers data using Modbus Poll and fount its data is in binary but 16-bit int.
Thus I try to convert the data to quint16 (with low and high bit) and send to the device using QModbusDataUnit, but it doesn't work.
Here's the code I use:
void Widget::on_lineEdit_RttSpeed_returnPressed() //Rotate Speed setting
{
    //Speed Range，0.1-100rpm，precision 0.1rpm
    QDoubleValidator *doubleValidator = new QDoubleValidator(this);
    doubleValidator->setRange(0.1,100,1);
    ui->lineEdit_RttSpeed->setValidator(doubleValidator);

    //Read data from LineEdit
    QString rotate_speed = ui->lineEdit_RttSpeed->text();
    //QString -> Float
    float port = rotate_speed.toFloat();
    //Float -> Qunit16
    union {
        struct {
            quint16 lo;
            quint16 hi;
        };
        float flt;
    } converter;
    converter.flt = port;
    //Qdebug Part
    qDebug() << "lo short"  << converter.lo;
    qDebug() << "hi short"  << converter.hi;

    // Send Write Request
    if (modbusDevice.state()==QModbusDevice::ConnectedState)
    {
        //QModbusDataUnit writeUnit(QModbusDataUnit::HoldingRegisters, 16, 2);
        //writeUnit.setValue(0, converter.flt);

        QModbusDataUnit writeUnit1(QModbusDataUnit::HoldingRegisters, 16, 1);
        writeUnit1.setValue(0, converter.hi); 
        QModbusDataUnit writeUnit2(QModbusDataUnit::HoldingRegisters, 17, 1); 
        writeUnit2.setValue(0, converter.lo); 
        
        //modbusDevice.sendWriteRequest(writeUnit, 1); //Device Slave ID: 1
        modbusDevice.sendWriteRequest(writeUnit1, 1);
        modbusDevice.sendWriteRequest(writeUnit2, 1);
        
        ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText("");
        ui->plainTextEdit->insertPlainText("Rotate Speed Set:" + QString(rotate_speed) + "rpm");
    }
    else
    {
        ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText("");
        ui->plainTextEdit->insertPlainText("Connection Fail");
    }
    return;
}


I'm new to this area and have no idea what to deal with next.

"using Modbus Poll" - please show us the command used and the response (this provides us with a starting point). "it doesn't work" - please add further detail (do you get an error, the wrong value etc). A Minimal, Reproducible Example would also help (i.e. port = 123.45 then try to write that value without the additional code).

You can send both registers in one packet. You should also check the return value of the sendWriteRequest() function.
It is also important to find out whether your device expects the float value in big or little endian format. If you are able to send the registers but the value doesn't seem to fit you can try to swap high and low.
QModbusDataUnit writeUnit1(QModbusDataUnit::HoldingRegisters, 16, 2);
writeUnit1.setValue(0, converter.hi);   
writeUnit1.setValue(1, converter.lo); 

if (auto *reply = modbusDevice.sendWriteRequest(writeUnit1, 1)) {
    if (!reply->isFinished()) {
       // succcesful sended
    }
}

